# Frontend. JavaScript. Как реализовать блок?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Нужно на дверь поместить красные круги (отмеченные зеленым), чтобы при наведении на них появлялся текст (отмеченный желтым). В верстке новичок, как реализовать ума не приложу, подскажите как сделать или укажите где можно про подобные вещи прочитать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Красные `div`ы с `border-radius: 50%` и `position: absolute` с нужными `left` и `top` и обработчиком click, да и всё

Comment: а адаптивно как это сделать? сделать родительским блок самой двери и относительно его сделать position: absolute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут нужен не клик, а события 'mouseover' / 'mouseout'.

Для изменения цвета при наведении используйте событие 'mouseover', при уходе - 'mouseout'

Подробнее здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку!